# CocoonJS for iPhone (NOT iPad)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoonjs

I've already spent two weeks trying to figure this out, and I'm unable to get it working... I made an HTML + Javascript game intended to work on both Android and iOS devices, so I used Ludei's CocoonJS (https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) to compile the project and generate two projects: one for Android and one for iOS.

I've already successfully uploaded the Android project, which is available at the PlayStore and works well on different devices, but I'm heaving REALLY trouble with the iOS one. The problem is that, somehow, when I upload the project using XCode, it is understood as being a universal application, though it is only intended for iPhone devices. Due to this, Apple keeps rejecting it, as the game's screen doesn't adapts to the iPad screens.

As I don't want the game to fit iPads, the "only" thing I have to do is to upload the game specifying that it only is intended for iPhone devices... But such a trivial thing begins to seem impossible after days and days of fails.

**What I've tried doing:**

CocoonJS doesn't let you specify a device family, so it seems that the XCode project it compiles is intended to be universal. However, before uploading the app via XCode, you can change its "Build" attributes.

- I've ensured one time and another that every option within the "Build" and the "Info" list points only at iPhone devices with iOS 7 (and not iPads nor universal).
- I've tried creating multiple projects on iTunes Connect to ensure that the whole process doesn't get messed with a previous universal binary or some other bizarre things.
- I'm only uploading screenshots for the 3.5 and 4 inches screens (iPhone 4 and iPhone 5).

**What I'm ALWAYS getting:**

An issue just when the project finsihes uploading saying that a localized screenshot is missing... I've searched over the net and it seems that this message may refer to various things, among them the fact that a supported device has no screenshot... Guess which one: iPad, I suppose!

The scariest part of everything is that when I open the details of the binary uploaded to iTunes Connect it shows a line:

```
Device family: iPhone / iPod, iPad
```

What the...!? What's the iPad doing here? I've tried almost everything and I'm not even to solve this... Maybe I'm missing something on the XCode "archiving" process, or I'm missing something on the iTunes project creation process... or maybe I'm missing something relating CocoonJS... I just don't know what else to do!

Anyone found something similar or can guess what can be happening?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue recently while uploading a game created with CocoonJS. The problem is that CocoonJS uses the info.plist for most of the settings and configurations. So, while looking into the plist, I found the issue.

There's an entry in the plist called `UIDeviceFamily` which overwrites the device selection in build settings. It's an array containing two values, 1 and 2. 1 denotes iPhone and iPod while 2 denotes iPad. So just delete the second entry (2) from this array and you should be good to go. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11).

Comment: Thanks, I managed to found the "UIDeviceFamily" after days of searching why my app appeared as universal, though I was setting the properties to iPhone only... It's kind of tricky to realize it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, nowadays it seems that Cocoon just export .xarchive, not .xcodeproj anymore, so, is there another way to do that? Or cocoon just build for Universal devices.

Comment: @FabioColombini you still can open .xarchive to access the .plist, just display the packet content (on mac), then navigate to the .app and display the content.